# Is there a way to control the encoding of XML inner text when using XmlWriter

Tags: c#, xml, character-encoding

I have a component that creates XML documents from objects through a combination of XML serialization and XSL transformation; the resulting documents are handled as `XDocument` objects. I use the `XDocument.Save(TextWriter)` method to save documents to disk using UTF-8 encoding, like:

```
XDocument doc = this.CreateDocumentFrom(...);
using (Stream stream = File.OpenWrite(...))
{
    var encoding = new UTF8Encoding(false);
    var settings = new XmlWriterSettings { Encoding = encoding };
    using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(stream, settings))
    {
        doc.Save(writer);
    }
}
```

Creating and writing the documents to disk works fine. Now, I´ve a requirement where text values within the XML must have a special encoding (only a small subset of the ASCII characters are allowed, let´s say upper- and lowercase letters except mutated vowels, digits and some special chars like comma, dot, ...). So, I thought I could simply inherit the `UTF8Encoding` class and override some methods to achieve the wanted behaviour by just filtering invalid characters. I tried to override `GetBytes(string)` and `GetString(byte[])`, but it didn´t work. It seems that the XmlWriter does not use the given encoding instance at all.

This is what I tried...

```
public sealed class CustomEncoding : UTF8Encoding 
{
    private const string ValidChars = "abc...xyzABC...XYZ0...9";

    public CustomEncoding() : base(false) { }

    public override byte[] GetBytes(string s)
    {
        char[] characters = s.Where(x => ValidChars.Contains(x)).ToArray();
        return base.GetBytes(characters);
    }

    ...
}
```

In the end, I´ve overridden almost everything to figure out which methods of the Encoding class are called by the writer, but only an overload of `GetCharCount(...)` is called when the `XmlWriter.Create(Stream, XmlWriterSettings)` method is called. I got the feeling that I am on the wrong track...

Creating a derived class from `XmlTextWriter` or `XmlWriter` felt also wrong to me, because then I can´t use `XmlWriter.Create(Stream, XmlWriterSettings)` any more, which is the recommended way to create XmlWriter instances.

Answer (score 2):

If it were me, I'd scrub the data (presumably an instance of a class?) before calling the `XmlWriter`.  I might even create a derived class from the class you're serializing and then serialize *that*.

As an example:

```
public class SomeFoo
{
  public string SomeTextValue {get; set;}
}

public class SomeDerivedFoo : SomeFoo
{
  private SomeDerivedFoo();
  public static SomeDerivedFoo CreateFromSomeFoo(SomeFoo someFoo)
  {
     base.SomeTextValue = //scrub your data here;
  }
}
```

Then, in your XmlWriter, you serialize `SomeDerivedFoo` AS `SomeFoo`.

Or, for a similar effect without a new class, create a `ScrubForSerialization()` method that will do the same thing on the original class.

Comment: Thanks alot; this answer was indeed helpful. I implemented a method that cleans the object graph before serialization...